# Crystal Reports.Net Invalid Parameter - String to date

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am using the crsytal reports in VS2008. I want to be able to filter the dates in my crystal report viewer depending on the input of the user through a datetime picker. My problem is the date field itself **in my database is in STRING format**. -_- Whenever I compare values through code, I parse it to datetime.

How do I fix this? Is there any way I could do a parse of the report field? I don't want/can't change my database field into datetime because that would entail altering my whole system.

**~ EDIT ~**

Upon clicking the filter button I have a **datetime picker** named FromCreated_DTime. I parse its value into short date string (ex. 1/01/2011) and then assign it to my string parameter field. Using the Select Expert formula, I applied your code. My parameter field is named actualStart:

```
Date (ToNumber (Right ({Projects.Actual_StartDate}, 4)),
  ToNumber (Left ({Projects.Actual_StartDate}, InStr ({Projects.Actual_StartDate}, "/")-1)),
  ToNumber (Mid ({Projects.Actual_StartDate}, 
                 InStr ({Projects.Actual_StartDate}, "/")+1, 
                 InStrRev({Projects.Actual_StartDate},"/")-InStr({Projects.Actual_StartDate}, "/")-1))
 ) 

 >= 

Date (ToNumber (Right ({?actualStart}, 4)),
  ToNumber (Left ({?actualStart}, InStr ({?actualStart}, "/")-1)),
  ToNumber (Mid ({?actualStart}, 
                 InStr ({?actualStart}, "/")+1, 
                 InStrRev({?actualStart},"/")-InStr({?actualStart}, "/")-1))
 )
```

### this is my code upon filter button click

```
    private void Filter_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

        cryRpt.Load("D:\\MY_THESIS\\WORKING FILES\\WindowsFormsApplication2\\WindowsFormsApplication2\\Reports\\Crystal Reports\\UsersReport.rpt");
        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "RITZEL-PC\\SQLEXPRESS";
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "NNIT-Admin";
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "password";
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "NNIT DB";

        Tables CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }

        // Create parameter objects
        ParameterFields myParams = new ParameterFields();

        //PARAMETER NAME
        ParameterField myParam = new ParameterField();
        ParameterDiscreteValue myDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        myParam.ParameterFieldName = "actualStart";

        myDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        myDiscreteValue.Value = FromCreated_DTime.Value.ToShortDateString();
        myParam.CurrentValues.Add(myDiscreteValue);
        myParams.Add(myParam);

        crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = myParams;
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you entering your `actualStart` parameter as a string? Why not enter it as a Crystal date parameter?

Comment: @MarkBannister because if I change it into a date parameter I get an error in my formula editor saying a string is required here (highlighting actualStart). Btw, thanks for answering back. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Do you mean in the selection formula editor? If so, I meant to change the string parameter to a date parameter, *and* replace all of the `>= Date (...` expression with a simple `>= {?actualStart}`.

Comment: @MarkBannister yes I get what you are trying to do. Converting the string to Date. That is why I made actualStart a string and also because its value will be a string value from the datetime picker. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood me - the database field has to be converted **to** a date **from** a string, because it is not stored as a date in the database. Given that the `actualStart` parameter is part of the report, there is no reason to declare it as a string and then **convert** it to be a date, if it can be **created** as a date parameter in the first place. I have updated my answer accordingly. Also, did you notice the comment I left against my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the format of your date field in database . here is an example:

```
stringvar yyear; 
stringvar mmonth; 
stringvar dday; 

dday := {ORDERS.ORDER_DATE}[5 to 6]; 
mmonth := {ORDERS.ORDER_DATE}[3 to 4]; 
yyear := {ORDERS.ORDER_DATE}[1 to 2]; 

if yyear < "50" then 
    date(tonumber(yyear)+2000,tonumber(mmonth),tonumber(dday)) 
else 
    date(tonumber(yyear)+1900,tonumber(mmonth),tonumber(dday))
```

Above code comes from: [Convert date from string to date format](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?t=67889)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can I put this kind of code in the formula editor? The format of my datefield in the database is just varchar10.

Comment: @Ritzel: Are the dates formatted as day-month-year, month-day-year, or some other format? Do they use numbers or three letter abbreviations for months? Do they use two or four digits for the year? Do single digit numbers include leading 0s? Are there separators between the day, month and year? (findcaiyzh's answer is based on a string formatted in the order year, month, day, with no separators, and with two characters for each of year, month and day.)

Comment: @MarkBannister Hi, thank you for your answer. As a matter of fact, I am experiencing problems with regards to findcaiyzh answer. My date is in varchar format, with "/" separators. Basically they're just one field in my database, a varchar10 field whose value is typically like this '12/6/2001' or '7/18/2011'. I tried using the CDate function of the formula editor but it just doesn't work.

Comment: @Ritzel: Hi, I have added a new answer - it assumes that the string is formatted in Month-Day-Year order. `CDate` requires an unambiguous string format - '12/6/2001' could mean either 12 June, 2001 *or* December 6, 2001, so it can't convert that value.

Answer (score 0):

One point... if you are planning on using the date as a selection parameter (what you describe), if you use the method outlined, you will beat your database very unkindly.  Not much of a problem in small databases (fewer records, smaller sized, etc.), but in a bigger database, you will run into problems.  The method described basically PULLS BACK EVERY (qualifying) RECORD, DOES THE CONVERSION, THEN DECIDES WHETHER IT SHOULD BE KEPT OR DISCARDED.  Those first 4(5) words should strike terror in your soul.  It's still a good method for DISPLAYING dates, if needed, but not for using string dates for record selection.

What you CAN (*should*) do is to create date parameters, then convert those into a suitable string expression, and use that to search the database.  You set the parameters once per report run.  You would have brought back every record, converted, compared, discarded, etc.  It makes my brain thrash just typing it.  :-D

Hope that helped and please don't read any sarcasm in to anything, nothing but good will is intended.

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you very much for your insightful comment. It seems very logical but how exactly would I be able to execute that? You see, I am having problems with the date selection parameter alone.

Comment: Ritzell, I am sorry.. I got caught up in a project and never got back to check on you.  Based on other comments and your update, I see some other points.  I assumed that converting from date to string would be easiest (UI entry), but that may not be.  Regardless, looking at the code again, I see some other potential problems.  The dates are stored in mixed hierarchy.  You could to a DIRECT comparison if they were in YYYY/MM/DD -- MOST significant to LEAST significant.  In the given format, my direct comparison idea would not help -- "01/01/2012" is LESS than "12/31/2004".  So....

Comment: You "might" be able to achieve what you need using SQL Expressions, or, if you are crafting the SQL used to pull records, using SQL functions to modify parameter and date fields (server-side) to do comparisons where.  By definition, SQL Expressions are performed at the server.  "Might":  Are SQL Expressions enabled? This may depend upon the data source.  For reports built on a COMMAND, you can always perform the conversions through SQL.  How to?  Try... SQL expressions to do part-comparison, and then ANDing the SQLExp in the SELECT EXPERT.  ADDING Answer as Example...

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: Given a character string called Projects.Actual_StartDate, formatted as `/`-separated fields in Month-Day-Year order, with a four-digit year and one-or-two-digit day and month values, the following formula should convert the string to a date and compare it with a Crystal date parameter called {?actualStart}:

```
Date (ToNumber (Right (TrimRight ({Projects.Actual_StartDate}), 4)),
      ToNumber (Left ({Projects.Actual_StartDate}, InStr ({Projects.Actual_StartDate}, "/")-1)),
      ToNumber (Mid ({Projects.Actual_StartDate}, 
                     InStr ({Projects.Actual_StartDate}, "/")+1, 
                     InStrRev({Projects.Actual_StartDate},"/")-InStr({Projects.Actual_StartDate}, "/")-1))
     )
 >= {?actualStart}
```

Comment: I tried this formula. I got no error saving it but while executing the report I still got 'the parameter is incorrect'. My parameter field is in string format. I updated my question with the code that I am using

Comment: @Ritzel: It occurred to me that the order_date field might be blank-padded to 10 characters at the end of the field, so I have added a `TrimRight` function to the year argument to remove any trailing spaces. If this version still doesn't select as required, can you confirm whether there may be some values that don't conform to the date format described?

Answer (score 0):

Example using SQL Expressions in Crystal -- depends upon data source wx the SQL Exp are enabled.

I am going to ASSuME that the field dates are in 10 chr strings, 
   i.e "mm/dd/yyyy"
I am going to ASSuME that your parameter is a string.  Using Date Picker is more convenient.  You can convert DP dates to strings.  Using {?actualStart}, {Projects.Actual_StartDate}

@SQLMonth

```
Left( {?actualStart}, 2 )  > 
   Left( {Projects.Actual_StartDate}, 2 )
```

@SQLDay

```
-- You can use SUBSTRING, but I'm being lazy.  
-- Time results for both and then decide

Right( Left( {?actualStart}, 5 ) , 2 )  > 
   Right( Left( {Projects.Actual_StartDate}, 5 ) , 2 )
```

@SQLYear

```
Right( {?actualStart}, 4 )  >
   Right( {Projects.Actual_StartDate}, 4 )
```

Then, in Select Expert, you can include:

```
(The REST of your selection code)  
AND
( {@SQLYear} AND {@SQLMonth} AND {@SQLDay} )
```

This would get pushed down to the server and reduce processing time, and return ONLY the records you want.  **

**  In theory...  I haven't tested this, I did it from memory.   :-)

Strangely enough, this would also be the code you would use if you used a SQL Command ( = "Crafting the SQL" programmaticly.***)

*** OK, I tried several different (mis-)spellings of Programatically, and FF spell check didn't like n'aer a-one.